# Elimination race tactics

Tags: racing, racing-strategy

I saw a bit of the Omnium racing televised this week, and while most of the events are straightforward, the Elimination race seems to require far deeper tactics than the others.

This may be just because I have never taken part in one of these, but can anyone here explain how to approach an elimination race in the format used at the Olympics (ie a sprint every 2 laps, last one is eliminated)?

My simplistic view suggests staying in the middle of the pack is key, but that's not how any of the races panned out, with wild breaks at seemingly random intervals.

Comment: [This race](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH98lrUPtss) shows how to win the event from the back of the field.

Comment: Wow - awesome race! And different technique to that used in the Olympics Elimination race I saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying in the middle is the worst thing to do as you can get boxed in unable to sprint your way out of trouble and the riders at the back can come around the top of you and drop you. You are reasonably safe at the front until there are fairly few riders left as it will be difficult for the whole group to come around you and you can sprint your way out of trouble. You are also ok at the back as you are in the slip stream of the group and can use that to slingshot the person in front at the crucial moment and sprint for the line. What you don't want to do is stay in the middle.